# How can I play a game ROM with a friend online?

Tags: games

I'm new to playing game ROMs with a Raspberry Pi. Is it possible to play against a friend who isn't sitting in the same room? For example, I have Super Tecmo Bowl on my Raspberry Pi. Is it possible for me to play against a friend who also has the same set up but who is located in another city? Just curious if this is possible and if there are instructions for doing so.